# How to send data using UDP from iOS to windows program?

Tags: ios, windows, ipad, udp, cross-platform

Title explains it all.

I know AsyncUDPSocket to transfer data between iOS app, and I also know WinSock to transfer data between windows program. (https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11740/A-simple-UDP-time-server-and-client-for-beginners)

I once want to combine them, but it does not work well. I can send data from iPad to windows, but not vice versa. Moreover, when I try to use real iPad instead of simulator in Xcode, I can't even send any data! I don't know whether the failure resides in the iPad app or the windows program.

My guess is that I dont use the correct library to do the function. Anybody able to provide me with the useful library? Or even better, tutorial for it? Thank you so much.

Comment: While using real device, are you connected to the same WLAN ?

Comment: yes, both are connected to the same wlan